# Logging on a website and do further browsing

Tags: java, android, httpclient, jsoup

I'm trying to receive the html of a website. For now I've tried it with Jsoup and HttpClient.

Well, the thing is that I can login onto the website, but I can't go further on the website. Everytime I'm trying to I become logged out instantly. I've already tried that with sending the needed cookies, but that does not help :/

My code is pretty big, so for now I'm just happy if you would only give me some tips and advices :)

Thanks!

Comment: hidden inputs ? i could elaborate more ... but my answer is pretty big and could not fit here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what you actually do or what website it is, it's hard to get more than a generic answer. That said, most websites implement various ways to protect against CSRF/XSRF, among which:

- Browser agent filtering
- HttpOnly cookies
- IP session tracking
- Referrer tracker
- Hidden inputs with tokens valid for a single request

Did you check for these?

It's worthwhile reading Jeff's take on the matter [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/09/cross-site-request-forgeries-and-you.html) and [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/preventing-csrf-and-xsrf-attacks.html).

Comment: Thanks :) gonna try that out. To the project : i want to receive data of ogame and display it in an android app